# Mongo java driver authentication not working properly

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to access mongodb from java using mongo java driver 3.4. I wrote below code to access mongodb and even though I entered wrong credentials while connecting I am able to access my database.

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("rupesh_user", "rupesh_db",
                    "admin123".toCharArray());
MongoClient mongoClient= new MongoClient( new ServerAddress( "localhost", 27017 ), Arrays.asList(credential));
```

When I am trying to access mongo database from terminal in ubuntu. Its asking for authentication.

```
> use rupesh_db
switched to db rupesh_db
> show collections
2017-08-03T13:07:52.970+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listCollections failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on rupesh_db to execute command { listCollections: 1.0, filter: {} }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
```

Comment: Thanks #4J41 Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: looks like you have created the credential but does that user has the 'readWrite' permission role on the DB?

Comment: #Rahul Kumar Yes that user has ReadWrite permission. Issue is from terminal I am unable to access same db without auth. But using mongo java driver no authentication required. I am totally confused. Please help me

Comment: I think you have to use db.auth('rupesh_user',"admin123"). or better I write it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

From Console you will have to authorize

```
> use rupesh_db
switched to db rupesh_db
> db.auth("rupesh_user","admin123")
> show collections
```

[More details](https://sites.google.com/site/itsjustalongname/home/mongodb/Mongodb-basic-authentication)

Comment: From terminal its working fine. My issue is Authentication is not working from mongo java driver